# Scrapy crawl behaves strangly

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Use Python 3.11 and scrapy 2.71 on Windows 10. Following the Scrapy [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-download-files-with-scrapy/)  downloading files from nirsoft.net, I made some adjustments for crawling another website (https://www.midi-karaoke.info) please take a look.

I'm not shure, but I hope to get most of html pages with my modified script (>100.000) but no .mid files.

This site behaves strange itself. It's a very flat design with >100.000 numbered pagenames. If I browse down to a Midi-file-link to download it, nothing happens. If I inspect the source in the browser and click on the .mid file I get it; or rename the page.extension to .mid in the addressfield of the browser with the link to the .mid file (https://www.midi-karaoke.info/21110cbd.html -> https://www.midi-karaoke.info/21110cbd.mid) I get it.

Furthermore changes made to my scrip,t sometimes they'r working but not at all. Next pass, next day, they may not work again with the same script. Here is what I use:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from webcrawler.items import WebcrawlerItem # import C:\..\scrapy\webcrawler\webcrawler\items.py

class WebcrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'webcrawl'
    allowed_domains = ['www.midi-karaoke.info']
    start_urls = ['https://www.midi-karaoke.info']

    # Redirections vermeiden ?
    custom_settings = {'REDIRECT_ENABLED': False}
    handle_httpstatus_list = [302, 301]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        # webseite befindet sich nur in '/'
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/'), deny_extensions=[], restrict_xpaths=('//a[@href]')), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
        # extrahiere 'href' links
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/'), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="MIDI"]',)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
        # href links die uns interessieren befinden sich in class='MIDI'   
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        file_url = response.css('.downloadline::attr(href)').getall() # hole alle gefundenen Seiten
        file_url = response.urljoin(file_url)       
        file_extension = file_url.split('.')[-1]
        # filtere links nach Dateien mir Extension (Optional)
        if file_extension not in ('mid' , 'html', 'zip'): 
            return
        #if '.ru.' in file_url or '.en.' in file_url:
         #   return
        item = WebcrawlerItem()
        item['file_urls'] = [file_url]
        item['original_file_name'] = file_url.split('/')[-1]
        yield item
```

This works sometimes and sometimes not. Please help.

```
 # Redirections vermeiden ?
    custom_settings = {'REDIRECT_ENABLED': False}
    handle_httpstatus_list = [302, 301]
```

settings.py:

```
# Scrapy settings for webcrawler project

BOT_NAME = 'webcrawler'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['webcrawler.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'webcrawler.spiders'
DUPEFILTER_DEBUG = False
REDIRECT_ENABLED = False 
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'webcrawler.pipelines.WebcrawlerPipeline': 1,
}
FILES_STORE = r"C:\Users\wiwa53\scrapy\webcrawler\downloads"
REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION = '2.7'
TWISTED_REACTOR = 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148'
```

items.py:

```
# Define here the models for your scraped items
import scrapy

class WebcrawlerItem(scrapy.Item):
    file_urls = scrapy.Field()
    original_file_name = scrapy.Field()
    files = scrapy.Field
```

pipelines.py:

```
# Define your item pipelines here
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline

class WebcrawlerPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):        
        file_name: str = request.url.split("/")[-1]
        #print(file_name)
        return file_name
```

Comment: Have you enabled the appropriate pipelines and settings for downloading?

Comment: Yes pipeline.py is set, .html I get all in the right place. Because there is no dir command on websites I'm not shure if that's all. But .html-pages with the .mid file-link I get shure.

Comment: Is the goal of you spider to download all of the `'.mid'` files?

Comment: Mainly Yes it is. But there is the description in .html files so I need them also at least. Best should be to get them all. How I said, .html is no problem to get with my script. And onetime I also get some of the .mid files (don't know why). But these .mid files are numbered in the way the html base-file was, so I need to rename them later with a next script step I work on it meanwhile.

Comment: This is what I have filtered from their sitemap file into excel:
`
Beatles/ Michelle 2.mid - midi\de\20d238c1.html midi\de\20d238c1.html
Beatles/ Michelle 3 (Караоке).mid- midi\de\20d23ab5.html 
`

Comment: After finishing my 2nd script renaming the once and coincidentally gotten .mid files related to the html files filtering group and songtitle for an appropriate readable filename, playing them, I determine most of the loaded .mid files are the same song crawled from different pages from where they'r linked to the correct file. So there is something very very strange with that site?! Maybe I get most of them through website cache, or so. May a timeout, pause for downloading them help, or should I try rotating browser identification. Please help.

Comment: Hey there... I was able to get a script working that downloads the mid files and organizes them into a folder structure based on the artist and song title....

Comment: Which parts of the html were you also trying to get?  Do you want all the text on each of the individual song pages?  In the spider you posted you are not attempting to grab any html elements.  There is no need to write a seperate script to rename the files. scrapy can do that for you.

Comment: I havn't tried playing any of the files back though.  I guess I should check to ensure they are not all the same as well

Comment: Alexander: that is what I see, too, many mid files are the same song. My 1st script try to loads all content so I have all html files (.ru.html, .en.html and .html), but no mid files. 2nd script try to filter and load only mid files - one of these test was succesfully but many mid files are the same. So I try around with beautifulsoup, extracting the links from html I have locally, get mid files , but many of them are also the same song - this drives me crazy...

Comment: Would you be so kind and post your functional script here?

Comment: Yes I can but you didnt answer my question about which parts of the text you are trying to extract since i dont see any of that in your example code.

Comment: Not in this script. I wrote another one with beautifulsoup(bs4), run over my local downloaded html files search a@href tags for '.mid' and while all the html-filestructure found .mid is the same I extract tag[3] for group and  tag[5] for songtitle and made a list in .xlsx to view the relationship to the later downloaded .midi files. Then I extract a list with all the urls point to .mid downloads and download them. This works fine for testing in bs4 but like I said, most of them are doublet. I only found out by hearing them and compare with the titles in the xlsx file. That's the story fornow.

Comment: Use the script i just uploaded all you need to do is uncomment the main function and run it as a script and it will download all of the "A's" from the site obviously you will need to run it from inside a scrapy project but don't use the command line.  Just run it as a regular python script

Comment: hopefully you can take it from there to adapt it to get the rest of the artists from B-Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few noticdable issues in your code. For example you have multiple rules for that will match the same url's, you also list a non-existing callback method `parse_items` in your rules.  You also haven't provided your `WebCrawlerItem` so its impossible to know if that has
the appropriate fields. I also don't see any attempt at all to extract description information that you mention needing.

Here is an example I made that scrapes the first page of the site which happens to be all of the `A`s and then parses the inner pages for the track information, and then downloads the files to their respective folder.

I just use a standard `scrapy.Spider` and I include versions of the item class and FilePipeline and all the custom settings in the same script:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline
# from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import os

class MyPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        return os.path.join(item['artist'], item['title'])

class WebcrawlerItem(scrapy.Item):
    file_urls = scrapy.Field()
    files = scrapy.Field()
    original_file_name = scrapy.Field()
    artist = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()

class WebcrawlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'webcrawl'
    allowed_domains = ['www.midi-karaoke.info']
    start_urls = ['https://www.midi-karaoke.info']
    custom_settings = {'REDIRECT_ENABLED': False}
    handle_httpstatus_list = [302, 301]

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        for link in response.xpath("//div[@class='folders_and_files']/a"):
            text = link.xpath('./text()').get()
            if link.xpath('./@class').get() == 'f':
                kw = {'title': text}
                callback = self.parse_item
            elif link.xpath('./text()').get() != '..':
                kw = {'artist': text}
                callback = self.parse
            else:
                continue
            url = response.urljoin(link.xpath('./@href').get())
            kw.update(kwargs)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=callback, cb_kwargs=kw)

    def parse_item(self, response, artist="", title=""):
        midi = response.xpath('//table[@class="MIDI"]//table//a/@href').get()
        link = response.urljoin(midi)
        item = WebcrawlerItem()
        item["artist"] = artist
        item["title"] = title
        item['file_urls'] = [link]
        item['original_file_name'] = midi
        yield item

# def main():
#     process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
#         "USER_AGNET": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
#         "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY": False,
#         "ITEM_PIPELINES" : {
#                 MyPipeline: 100,
#                 },
#         "FILES_STORE": './folder',
#         "FILES_URLS_FIELD": 'file_urls',
#         "FILES_RESULT_FIELD": 'files',
#         })
#     process.crawl(WebcrawlSpider)
#     process.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, find out whats going on there. If you want all details on mine I post them and edit my questin on top.

Comment: @wiwa53 let me know if you have any questions and when you get it to work don't forget to come back mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Your script works fine, made a nice structure; I've learned more basics in python and scrapy (and am not finished yet). But if you hear the single mid files, its the same result I had: most are wrong to the titles and repeated the same file. Look into folder Abba - well known songs - but nothing matches. Whats on with that website?

Comment: That's the reason why I concentrate now on silenium, hope the download from a browser environment is more flawness. But here I have invest a lot of brain and time to learn new techniques.

Comment: Got to run a short selenium, firefox and webdriver -script point direkt to a midi file and get the wrong file too. This website is a horror. Accept your answere anyway - its the best solution, Thanks so much.

Comment: None of those are issues with the spider... that is simply how the website is structured.

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean with structured. What I see it's simply flat and all the links point into the flat structure. Maybe there is something that sees a bot and then delivers the files from an other store randomly? Is this conceivable? Is it possible in scrapy/python to hide to be a bot?

Comment: Is it possible... sure.  I don't believe that is what is actually happening though.  More likely whatever software is being used to serve this site is probably outdated and functioning incorrectly.  @wiwa53